# Cannot test class inside module[uninitialized constant] Rspec

Tags: rspec-rails

This is my authentication file:

```
module Command
  class AuthenticateUser
    prepend SimpleCommand
    ...
  end
end
```

And then I made a test with this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Command::AuthenticateUser do

 ...
end
```

When I ran the test, got this error:

```
# --- Caused by: ---
# NameError:
#   uninitialized constant Command
#   ./spec/commands/authenticate_user_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

Not sure where is the problem with my code, could you give some suggestions Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class AuthenticateUser

    prepend SimpleCommand
    ...
end
```

&

```
require 'rails_helper'

    describe AuthenticateUser do
    ...
end
```